# context not working in passing the intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have `AsyncTask` named `SigninActivity`. It gets some json file & inside its `onPostExecute` I run another `AsyncTask` named `getprevorder`. So when a user login is confirmed that triggers different intents accordingly one of which is another `AsyncTask` providing context throughout. However the `Intent` which is called at the end is not working and giving error:

`"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"`

```
package com.example.sony.iwashapp;
//import packages

public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private String usermail, password;
private String controlname;
private Context context;
private int byGetOrPost = 0;

private ProgressDialog pd;


//flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
public SigninActivity(Context context, String c1, int flag) {
    this.context = context;
    controlname = c1;

    byGetOrPost = flag;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd.setTitle("Please wait...");

    pd.show();


}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    try {
        usermail = (String) arg0[0];
        password = (String) arg0[1];

        String link = "http://apps.iwashlaundry.in/login/";
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("usermail", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(usermail, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(link);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            break;
        }
        String s = sb.toString();
        Log.d("server reply", s);
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    String server_reply = result;
    try {
        pd.dismiss();
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(server_reply);
        String status = json.getString("status_message");

        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("Login Successful")) {


            if (controlname.equalsIgnoreCase("previousorder")) {

                new getprevorder(context).execute();

                // Toast.makeText(context,"login first before place your order",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (controlname.equalsIgnoreCase("placeorder")) { //Toast.makeText(context,"login first before checking previous orders",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, orderconfirm.class);
                i.putExtra("usermail", usermail);
                context.startActivity(i);

            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, dashboard.class);
                context.startActivity(i);

            }


        } else
            Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class getprevorder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Context context2;
    ProgressDialog pd2;


    //flag 0 means get and 1 means post.(By default it is get.)
    public getprevorder(Context c) {
        context2 = c;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        pd2 = new ProgressDialog(context2);
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd2.setTitle("Please wait...");

        pd2.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        try {


            String link = "http://apps.iwashlaundry.in/previous-order/";
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("usermail", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(usermail, "UTF-8");


            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            String s = sb.toString();
            Log.d("server reply", s);
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pd2.dismiss();

        String prevlist = result;
        // prevlist="[{\"OrderID\":\"1\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:12:25\",\"Services\":[\"Washing\",\"ironing\",\"woollen washing\",\"washing + folding\"],\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"11-10-15 10:00-1:00\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"13-10-15 10:00-1:00\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"15\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"5kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"400\",\"OrderStage\":\"4\"},{\"OrderID\":\"13\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:16:25\",\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"12-10-15 10\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"12-15-10 12\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"20\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"10kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"250\",\"OrderStage\":\"1\"},{\"OrderID\":\"14\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:16:28\",\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"12-10-15 10\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"12-15-10 12\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"22\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"7kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"750\",\"OrderStage\":\"3\"},{\"OrderID\":\"15\",\"userID\":\"mananpandya.sgvu@gmail.com\",\"Order_Given\":\"2015-10-13 11:16:28\",\"Schedule_Pickup\":\"12-10-15 10\",\"Schedule_Delivery\":\"12-15-10 12\",\"No_Of_Clothes\":\"22\",\"Weight_Clothes\":\"7kg\",\"Total_Amount\":\"750\",\"OrderStage\":\"2\"}]";


        try {

//////Intent i.e not working/////
            Intent i = new Intent(context2, previousorder.class);
            //i.putExtra("usermail",usermail);
            // i.putExtra("prevlist",prevlist);
            context.startActivity(i);

            //Toast.makeText(context,usermail+prevlist,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure which line is triggering the crash. Could you highlight it?

Comment: It is in last 10 lines after "//////Intent i.e not working/////"

Answer (score 0):

You call `getString()` at `JSONObject`:

```
String status = json.getString("status_message");
```

make sure that `status_message` field really exists inside given json. If it could be missed in some situations then surround this block with [try catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Comment: I dont know about the getString,one thing is sure I that have to pass usermail & prevlist(initially commented )to another activity.I am getting the values from server but the intent is not fetching the values .Waht about the context here I used i think it is correct ???

Comment: I am not calling a jsonboject, initially it is only a string name "prevlist"

Comment: I am still facing the issue